# Help required in user control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I am using a user control (.ascx) as below

```
 <div class="ui-widget" id="w_instruction">
        <div class="ui-state-instruction ui-corner-all w-msg"> 
                    <a id="btn_instruction_close" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" style="float:right;"><img src="../../Images/i_close_blue.png" border="0"/></a>
                    <img src="../../Images/i_info_24.png" align="absmiddle"/>
                    <span id="i_msg"></span>
        </div>
    </div> // this code goes in to instruction.ascx
```

In my aspx page I am using this user control like below.

```
 <%Html.RenderPartial("Instruction"); %>
```

and using jquery I am changing the message in the div.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#i_msg").text("Please Enter the Infringement Details.");
        </script>
```

It was working fine. But now I want to use this user control at two different places in a page.
I need some way to differentiate the user control at both places. Any thougth process is welcome.

**NOTE**- I am using ASP.net MVC 2 application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you using a strongly typed control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<div class="ui-widget" id="w_instruction">
    <div class="ui-state-instruction ui-corner-all w-msg"> 
        <a id="btn_instruction_close" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" style="float:right;">
            <img src="../../Images/i_close_blue.png" border="0"/>
        </a>
        <img src="../../Images/i_info_24.png" align="absmiddle"/>
        <span id="i_msg"><%= Html.Encode(Model) %></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then include the control in different places with different model:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Instruction", "text 1"); %>
```

and another place:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Instruction", "text 2"); %>
```

If you need to modify the text using javascript wrap the user control by a div with specific id and use a class selector.

Comment: The Model property will be of the type used in your control declaration (in this case string). The value is passed when we render the partial. The `Html.Encode` ensures that this string is properly html encoded to avoid XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each of the partials within a divs within different IDs, then just use both the IDS:

```
var targetA = $("#divA #i_msg");
var targetB = $("#divB #i_msg");
```

However, just note that this is totally wrong. You should never have duplicate IDs on the page as it's invalid markup. You should apply class names instead of IDs:

```
<div id="divC">
    /* Created by RenderPartial */
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <div class="ui-state-instruction ui-corner-all w-msg"> 
            ....
            <span class="msg"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when you wrap this in another div with the ID `divC`, you'd right something like:

```
var targetB = $("#divC .msg");
```

Comment: Yes, Looking a good approach as of now. but waiting for some more answers. Thanks.